# Redshift: Chaining resultant columns of each query into a table

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, amazon-redshift, common-table-expression

I have around 50 queries in production. Each of the queries returns two columns - userid and some computed column

The requirement is that all these queries should put the computed columns in the resultant table by joining it through userid.

For example:-

Query 1st returns following columns with data:-

```
-------------
userid | c1 |
-------------
```

Similarly Query 2nd:-

```
-------------
userid | c2 |
-------------
```

Query 50th:-

```
-------------
userid | c50 |
-------------
```

Now computed columns output of each of these queries should be appended to a resultant master table like:-

```
--------------------------------------------------
userid | c1 | c2 | c3 |..............| c49 | c50 |
--------------------------------------------------
```

Now most naïve way would be to write output of each query into a separate temp tables and join each of the tables on userid to a single resultant table. The problem with this I don't want to pollute the namespaces to this extent by creating temp tables and as this is redshift and tables are really huge , committing each temp table itself would have a major cost associated in terms of storage.

Next solution I have thought is using 'with' CTEs :-

```
insert into Resultant
with rel1 as (select userid, c1 from t1 ),
rel2 as (select userid,c2 from t2 ),
.
.
rel50 as (select userid, c50 from t50)
select * from rel1 inner join rel2 on rel1.userid = rel2.userid 
inner join rel3 on rel2.userid = rel3.userid
...
...
inner join rel50 on rel49.userid = rel50.userid
```

I don't know how optimized this solution is. Redshift [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_WITH_clause.html) mentions:-

> Where possible, WITH clause subqueries that are referenced multiple times are optimized as common subexpressions; that is, it may be possible to evaluate a WITH subquery once and reuse its results.

Another method could be using 50 update joins :-

```
update resultant set resultant.col1 = (select Q.col1 from ("inner query that generates userid and col1) Q inner join resultant on resultant.userid = Q.userid );
update resultant set resultant.col2 = (select Q.col2 from ("inner query that generates userid and col1) Q inner join resultant on resultant.userid = Q.userid );
update resultant set resultant.col50 = (select Q.col50 from ("inner query that generates userid and col1) Q inner join resultant on resultant.userid = Q.userid );
```

Will this approach incur more cost? As Redshift is column based, I am expecting it will not have to update an entire row.

Is there a way to do this operation in stored procedures which will be way more optimized than these two approaches? Ideally  I would like to avoid stored procedures if absolutely not necessary.
Each query returns approx ~50GB of resultset.

Comment: When you update one column, you update the entire row.  The values in each column have a row number, and the row number must be the same for each column.  The original row has its delete_xid set, and a whole new row is created, for each column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interesting question.  Definitely don't go down the UPDATE path - Redshift is columnar and this will make a mess out of the table.

Joining will work but I also don't expect it will be ideal.  The number of JOINs you are talking about might hit up against the Redshift maximum number of independent parts in a query.  You can get around this by using temp tables.  Still I don't think this will be great performance.  It may be acceptable if the data is small.

I'd look into doing the by UNIONing the results of the queries with a query identifier.  Then look to build the wide format using GROUP BY in an outer select.  This creates the least number of new table structures and uses the faster grouping method (than joining).  If the amount of data is large it will make sense to make a temp table for the UNION results that has a distribution key of userid.  This will allow the GROUP BY operation to run slice-local vs needing to redistribute the data.  The expense of making the temp table will only be offset if the amount of data is large.

The UNION output would be something like:

```
userid | queryid | value
```

Then a query like:

```
select userid, min(decode(queryid, 1, value)) as c1, min(decode(queryid, 2, value)) as c2, ...
from union_data
group by userid;
```

I expect this is faster than either of the methods you outlined but there may yet be a better way.